# How to install optional update KB5007253 if it is not listed?

Tags: windows-10, windows-update

I have read that optional Windows 10 update KB5007253 should fix network printing errors, so I'd like to install it. I checked the official page for this update: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/november-22-2021-kb5007253-os-builds-19041-1387-19042-1387-19043-1387-and-19044-1387-preview-d1847be9-46c1-49fc-bf56-1d469fc1b3af

> Go to Settings > Update & Security > Windows Update. In the Optional updates available area, you’ll find the link to download and install the update.

There is no entry for KB5007253 there. I use Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.19043.1348], I have checked for the latest updates using a button on the main page of Windows Update, and I got all the updates for my version of Windows. How do I install KB5007253? Will it be installed automatically later? I really need to test a fix for network printing.

Comment: You can download the update here: https://www.catalog.update.microsoft.com/Search.aspx?q=KB5007253

Comment: Nice, thanks a lot! Also, it is listed as PREVIEW of cummulative update in that list. Does it mean that Microsoft had not confirmed it for regular use?

Comment: @IvanP. - On the page you linked to it indicates there won’t be a monthly cumulative update in December. Which means the patch that includes this fix which isn’t a preview update will be released in January. Are you sure you are running Windows 10 21H2? It should be offered to you through Windows Update unless a GPO is set to otherwise wait a period of time. So download it manually [here](https://www.catalog.update.microsoft.com/Search.aspx?q=KB5007253). The update by the way absolutely does NOT require you to be running an Insider Preview build as the answer suggests.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you read the page you link to it is a PREVIEW for the December release. So second Tuesday in December.

Comment: So, this update will be automatically installed on second Tuesday of December and the simplest solution is just to wait, right?

Comment: Not quite. It will be progressively rolled out from that date randomly to users automatically. Microsoft needs to manage bandwidth. But you can manually update then by going to Windows Update in settings. You can also in *Settings - Update and Security - Windows Insider* join the beta program for updates.

Comment: @user1644677 - The update the author is asking about does not actually require the machine be enrolled into the Release Preview channel

Comment: It appeared as Optional update in update center, I installed it and it helped with printing problem. Great!

Answer (score 1):

> There is no entry for KB5007253 there. I use Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.19043.1348] , I have checked for the latest updates using a button on the main page of Windows Update, and I got all the updates for my version of Windows.

There are any number of reasons Windows Update would not be offering KB5007253.  The most likely reason, is you have the group policy enabled, that delays cumulative updates by certain amount of time enabled. A second explanation, for the update not being listed, is that Windows 11 is pending to be installed.

> How do I install KB5007253?

Of course since the update is optional you can simply download and install it manually [here](https://www.catalog.update.microsoft.com/Search.aspx?q=KB5007253)

> Will it be installed automatically later?

If you simply wait the fixes included in KB5007253 will be contained in the next monthly cumulative update (B update) that will happen in January. C and D updates are optional updates, which is the reason KB5007253, is labeled as an optional update.

Answer (score 0):

In the link you provided, it tells you that you can download it directly from the catalog [here](https://www.catalog.update.microsoft.com/Search.aspx?q=KB5007253). You should be able to download and install it via that link.